# How to rename a file while uploading

Tags: c#

I am uploading file.so I want to change my file name.

```
 string createfolder = "E:/tmp/jobres/" + uId;
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createfolder);
 string newfilename = txtname.Text + "Resume" + fileExtension;
 AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(createfolder,newfilename ));
```

This time file is in different format then its not replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string createfolder = "E:/tmp/jobres/" + uId;

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createfolder);

//AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(createfolder,"Give Something Here whatever is changing at all time like time value"+AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));

AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(createfolder,"DateTime.Now"+AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```